# CrossMedia.Camera backs to main page after take a photo

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Plugin.CrossMedia in Xamarin Forms, and sometimes, after the camera takes a photo, the application turn back to main page, and all worked is lost in actual page, including the image. This occurs on Android (5, and 6).

I'm doing this:

```
if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
{
    return;
}

var photoName= "photo.png";
var sizeImg= Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Small;
var mediaOptions = new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
{
    SaveToAlbum = false,
    AllowCropping = true,
    DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Rear,
    Name = photoName,
    PhotoSize = sizeImg
};

using (var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(mediaOptions))
{
    if (file == null)
        return;

    var filePath = file.Path;

      ... move image

}
```

Comment: The OS is killing off processes to free memory for the camera's usage, which OS? Android?

Comment: It's killing off on Android

Answer (score 3):

When the OS needs memory to perform your app's request, in this case using the camera, having an Activity get restarted is common occurrence on lower end devices; limited memory, `Android One` and the new Oreo-based `Android Go` devices.

`Xamarin.Forms` runs within a single `Activity` (typically the template-created `MainActivity`) and its Application & Page lifecycle events are mapped *within* the Activities' lifecycle events.

`Xamarin.Forms`' Termination:

> Note that there is no method for application termination. Under normal circumstances (ie. not a crash) application termination will happen fom the OnSleep state, without any additional notifications to your code.

Re: [Forms' Lifecycle Methods](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/app-lifecycle/)

Some practices to follow:

- Profile your app's memory usage
- Ensure that you are releasing resources that are no longer needed, images are *typically* the largest consumer of memory within an app
- Request a higher importance for your app when launching an external app by creating a dummy `Service` and request a `ImportanceReason.ServiceInUse` from the Android OS.

  ```
  Note: This does not prevent the OS from terminating your process,
        it provides another hint to the OS...
  ```
- When opening external apps such as the camera, Chrome via Custom Tabs (`Xamarin.Auth`), etc... and the user is expecting to return to the same state, ensure that you have persisted your app's state so you can restore it.
- Read up on the [Android's Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) so when the Activity's `OnCreate` is called with a `Bundle` you know that your app is restarting and you can retrieve and pass some app specific state information to your Forms' Application subclass that determine what Forms navigation stack to rebuild and which page to open, i.e.:

  ```
  if (bundle is null)
      LoadApplication(new App());
  else
  {
      var restoreAppState = GetPriorAppState();
      LoadApplication(new App(restoreAppState.Restore2Page));
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this problem only occurs with lower devices. I will try to improve performance.